# Get higher value object in the item field

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using this expression to get the most valuable item:

```
var notaMaisVelha = resultCrawler.Ranges.Max(c => c.Item);
```

The problem is that this expression returns the value of the item field and I wanted the object.

How do I get the object with the largest item field?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort them by `Item` and pick the first item as it will be the max :

```
var notaMaisVelha = resultCrawler.Ranges.OrderByDescending(c => c.Item).First();
```

This will give the object which has the max value for the `Item` in `Ranges` collection.

### Note:

`First()` will throw exception if there is no items in the collection, there is another method `FirstOrDefault()` which would return `null` if there is no item in the collection but will required null check when consuming it.

Comment: I think you beat me to it by a few seconds :)

Comment: @johnny5 yeah looks like so..

Answer (score 1):

Just user order by descending and take the top 1

```
resultCrawler.Ranges.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item).FirstOrDefault();
```